# Wordpress GutenBurg Block - React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

When I try to add `Tooltip` in WordPress while creating `gutenburg blocks`
it show an error. Check below

> Invariant Violation: Minified React error #143; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=143
>
> React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Here is my code which is I'm trying.

```
<Fragment>
    <div className="my-block-class">
        <Tooltip text={ __( 'Select Grid' ) }>
            { getIcon( 'block-icon', true ) }
        </Tooltip>
    </div>
    <InnerBlocks
        template={ this.getBlockTemplate() }
        templateLock="all"
        allowedBlocks={ [ 'hwb/my-block' ] }
    />
</Fragment>
```

Problem is in this code.

```
<Tooltip text={ __( 'Select Grid' ) }>
    { getIcon( 'block-icon', true ) }
</Tooltip>
```

When I remove `Tooltip` code works fine.

**Update**

`getIcon()` return the `svg` icon I also tried `Dashicon` it is not working that's mean problem is not in `geticon()` function.

I also tried it like this.

```
<Tooltip text={ __( 'Select Grid' ) }>
    <Dashicon icon="edit" />
</Tooltip>
```

Comment: What does the `getIcon` function look like? Please include that in your question.

Comment: `getIcon()` is a function that return `svg` please check the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a some problem in `getIcon` function I tried `Dashicon` is working fine for me. You probably missed to import the `Dashicon` from `wp-components`

Try this one.

```
const { Tooltip, Dashicon } = wp.components;

<Tooltip text={ __( 'Select Grid' ) }>
    <Dashicon icon="edit" />
</Tooltip>
```